# JQuery 3.6.0 filter events for nothing found?

Tags: jquery, events, filter

In the following little piece of code.  I'm trying to hide the spinner when filter returns nothing.  It works when filter returns something which the hide() function is called at the end but when filter returns nothing, I'm unable to figure out where to hide the spinner when filter returns nothing

```
var $rows = $(TableName + ' tr').not('thead tr');

$('#FilterSpinner').show();

$rows.show().filter(function () {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
}).hide('fast', function () {
    $('#FilterSpinner').hide(); // Works fine
});
```

I don't mind having a different way of filtering in order to show a spinner when filtering starts and hide the spinner when completed either with nothing or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to:

- Show all rows;
- Find rows matching some filter criteria;
- hide those matching the filter;
- hide your spinner once done, making sure to wait until the previous step is finished;

You are 90% of the way there AFAICT - maybe you were looking for a cleverer solution but simply splitting your code up a bit makes it easy.  How about something like this:

```
// 1. Show all rows
$rows.show();

// 2. Find matches
var $filtered = $rows.filter(function () {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
});

// 3. Hide any matches, then hide the spinner
if ($filtered.length) {
    $filtered.hide('fast', function () {
        $('#FilterSpinner').hide();
    });
} else {
    // ... or simply hide the spinner if there are no matches
    $('#FilterSpinner').hide();
}
```

Side note - you could also cache your spinner selector, like you already are doing with other variables:

```
var $spinner = $('#FilterSpinner');
...
$spinner.hide();
```

Comment: Excellent I buy it.  I did apply your code and here the complete function
https://jsfiddle.net/GearWorld/fjrpc2g0/17/